# Application Control Interface (API) questions for AIX LPARs

Tags: deepsecurity

My company is trying to onboard a new customer and the developer has a few questions.

**Explanation**

When we provision AIX Virtual Machines (VM) in IBM Cloud, we need to register a computer object using the Application Programming Interface (API).

**Questions**

- What would be the objecttype for *(____ MachineSummary)* that we would
  use?
- If Trend Micro Deep Security has been used to register AIX LPARs,
  what is the *"objectType"*?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this is an API question about creating computers using the Deep Security SDK (unrelated to application control). While there is a large amount of information in the Computers object, much of that information is read-only (such as most/all of the different of machine summaries).

To create a computer, the only required field is the computer's hostName. Other fields such as policyID may be important to set, or to change quickly after creation, in order to ensure protection for the computer.

Comment: Hi Morgan!

I really appreciate your help an patience.

Unfortunately, the project was cancelled.

If I have any question or concern, I'll ask a new question.